# How can I go about rewriting the sql statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql statement that I use to send mail. The output is as follows as an example.

```
    select 'mail body content-1' as 'mailBody','11/9/221' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
    union all
    select 'mail body content-2' as 'mailBody','11/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','b@b.com' as 'mail'
    union all
    select 'mail body content-3' as 'mailBody','10/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
```

[image]

Here, I send mail by "group by" for each mail and combining the data with "xml for path".

My full code is as below

```
DECLARE @mail varchar(255)=''
DECLARE @mailBody nvarchar(max)=''
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

    select m.mail from (
        --sql String
        select 'mail body content-1' as 'mailBody','11/9/221' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-2' as 'mailBody','11/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','b@b.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-3' as 'mailBody','10/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        --sql String/
    ) m group by m.mail

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Mail Cursor
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @mail

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN



set @mailBody=(select c.mailBody as 'span',c.mailFooter as 'small' from (
        --sql String
        select 'mail body content-1' as 'mailBody','11/9/221' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-2' as 'mailBody','11/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','b@b.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-3' as 'mailBody','10/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        --sql String/
) c where c.mail=@mail
for XML PATH ('div')
)
    select  @mail,@mailBody
    --EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail


FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @mail
END

CLOSE db_cursor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Mail Cursor/

DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

As a result it gives me the following output.

[image]

My problem here is that I have to write the same "sql string" sentence 2 times.

1. To group
2. To use in "for xml path"

How can I get rid of this recurrence?

The "sql string" is constantly changing. But there is a field called "mail" in every sql statement. I plan to save it as a procedure and use it all the time.

Is my path the right path?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

I'm undecided on what to do with String Agg, Conditional "why" loop, sp_execute, insert into @tempTable.

Comment: Inserting into a temp table, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f71ee8a658f1159d3464b99e9032c811    This is always easier, and simpler, then using STRING_AGG and/or `sp_execute` .

Comment: You have multiple questions/issues here. The constantly changing SQL string seems to be just data for the queries. In that case, you should store the data in a table (permanent or temporary) or pass it as a parameter (TVP, XML, or JSON). That way, you don't need to change code when the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a with block to generate the xml path for the loop:

```
DECLARE @mail varchar(255)=''
DECLARE @mailBody nvarchar(max)='';
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

    with tmp as (
        --sql String
        select 'mail body content-1' as 'mailBody','11/9/221' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-2' as 'mailBody','11/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','b@b.com' as 'mail'
        union all
        select 'mail body content-3' as 'mailBody','10/09/2021' as 'mailFooter','a@a.com' as 'mail'
        --sql String/
    )
    select m.mail, (select c.mailBody as 'span',c.mailFooter as 'small' from tmp c where c.mail=m.mail for XML PATH ('div'))
    from tmp m group by m.mail;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Mail Cursor
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @mail, @mailBody

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    select  @mail,@mailBody
    --EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @mail, @mailBody
END

CLOSE db_cursor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Mail Cursor/

DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```